# What is $dy$ in the 1-form $\alpha |_y := ([\beta,y],dy) $

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, differential-forms, vector-bundles, connections

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Consider the adjoint action of $ G$ on its Lie algebra, and  let $(.,.)$ be a $G$-invariant inner product on $\mathfrak{g}.$ Let $\beta \in \mathfrak{g}.$

In some notes I'm reading, there is a 1-form defined by
$$\alpha |_y := ([\beta,y],dy)  \qquad y \in \mathfrak{g}$$

1. What is the definition of $dy$ in the expression of $\alpha|_y$? I would think it is $dy_1 \wedge ...\wedge dy_n$, where $y_i$ are the global coordinates functions on $\mathfrak{g}$, but since $\alpha$ is a 1-form, this is not possible.
2. If $ X \in \mathfrak{g}$, how to evaluate $\alpha |_y$ at the tangent vector $X_\mathfrak{g}(y):= \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=0} e^{tX}.y = [X,y]. $

**Edit**: The author has defined a 1-form in more general context as follows,

> Let $p: E \rightarrow M$ be a $G$- equivariant vector bundle provided with a covariant derivative $\nabla^E.$ Let $\nabla ^{p^*E}$ be the induced covariant derivative on the bundle $p^*E \rightarrow E$ and  $\mathbf{y}$ be the tautological section of $p^*E$. Let $\alpha$ be the 1-form defined by $$\alpha=(\mathcal{L}(\beta) \mathbf{y}, \nabla^{p^*E} \mathbf{y})_E.$$

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Write, for example, $y=\sum y^i e_i$, where $\{e_i\}$ is a $(\cdot,\cdot)$-orthonormal basis for $\mathfrak g$. Now compute.